# Get the output of intermediate layer tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have to get the output of intermediate layer in Tensorflow and compute the gradient respect to output instead of the weigths. This way returns me None, is this the rigth way to get the output and manipulate it? Logits is the vector containing the output of every layer.

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as tape:
     logits.append(mnist_model.layers[0](images, training=True))
     logits.append(mnist_model.layers[1](mnist_model.layers[0].output, training=True))
     logits.append(mnist_model.layers[2](mnist_model.layers[1].output, training=True))
     output = mnist_model(images, training=True)
     loss_value = loss_object(labels, output)
     loss_history.append(loss_value.numpy().mean())

grads0 = tape.gradient(loss_value, logits[0])
grads1 = tape.gradient(loss_value, logits[1])
grads2 = tape.gradient(loss_value, logits[2])
```

Comment: compute the gradient respect to it instead of the weight...? Can you reproducible code with none output?

Comment: I mean that I want to compute the gradient respect to the output instead of respect to the weigths. I dont't know if how I compute the output of every layer is rigth.

Answer (score 0):

Get the output of intermediate layer using `model.get_layer("layer_name")` and find the below sample code

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    mid_layer = mnist_model.get_layer[layer_index].output
    loss = loss_object(labels, mid_layer)

grads = tape.gradient(loss, inp)
```

Either use layer_index or layer_name to get output of desired layer.